Rails query output row # 1 and then continue to row # 3
Row # 1 only output 1 record continue the rest on Row 3
- if @local_news.present?
  %h4.homepage-heading
  .row#local_news
    - @local_news.each do |news|
      .col-sm-12
        = render 'news_article', article: news, length: 160
%hr

Row # 2
- if @local_ads.present?
  %h4.homepage-heading
  .row#local_ads
    - @local_ads.each do |ads|
      .col-sm-12
        = render 'ad'
%hr

Row # 3 continue query from #Row 1

If you want to keep that structure, what about first, *remaining = @local_news. Then output first on row #1 and iterate remaining for row #3.

Use index:
- if @local_news.present?
  %h4.homepage-heading
  .row
    - @local_news.each_with_index do |article, i|
      - if i == 1
        - @local_ads.each do |ad|
          .col-sm-12
            = render ad
      .col-sm-12
        = render 'news_article', article: article, length: 160

